# Is there a DOT bundle for TextMate?

Tags: textmate, graphviz, dot, textmatebundles

Is there such a thing as a [DOT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOT_language) bundle for TextMate?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes there is.

It's called ***graphviz***, and you can find it either in the [official TM repo](http://svn.textmate.org/trunk/Bundles/Graphviz.tmbundle/) or in the un-official TM github repo. Both are available to install/update via the *GetBundles* GUI.

Like other TM Bundles, if you have this Bundle installed and you open a file with a .dot extension, then TM will open it in that scope.

It's a lean package, but it does everything i want, which is syntax highlighting for *dot* files and i can generate graphs with cmd-R.

Comment: Note that if you installed dot/graphviz via macports, you'll need to tell textmate where to find the binary for dot.

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking for additional integration of dot in OSX you might want to try the [QuickLook Plugin](https://github.com/besi/quicklook-dot/downloads) I created. This allows you to use QuickLook and Preview in a Finder window:

[image: screenshot]

Please make sure that the `dot` command is globally available. Refer to the [Readme](https://github.com/besi/quicklook-dot#readme) for more information.

Comment: On my Mac, I followed the installation instructions as mentioned by you. But the problem is I have MS-WORD installed too, which 'intercepts' the SPACE-bar instruction I choose on any .dot file, and simply proceeds to display the contents of the .dot file, instead of the preview I wanted.

Any suggestions for this please?